# Successive STFT transforms with tensorflow increases signal amplitude

Tags: tensorflow, signal-processing, fft

I currently need to include STFT layers in a neural network, and I am using [tensorflow's STFT](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/stft?hl=zh-cn). 
To test it, I successively applied STFT and iSTFT transforms several time on a signal, and the amplitude of the signal grows with each transform. 
The parameters I used are the following (both for STFT and iSTFT):

```
STFT = tf.signal.stft(np.array(sig), frame_length=174, frame_step=43, fft_length=174)
```

I tried [librosa's STFT](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html) with the exact same parameters and this doesn't happen (the signal is the exact same after each transform). Is this normal behaviour? Am I missing something?

Edit: Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

This is what an simple sine looks like after three consecutive STFT/iSTFT with librosa (you only see one curve because they are merged, as should be)

[image]

This is what the same curve looks like after three consecutive STFT/iSTFT with tensorflow. The original sine wave is in blue, I get the yellow curve after one STFT/iSTFT, then green, then red.

Here is the exact code:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

LENGTH=88

def get_STFT_librosa(sig):
    fft_size = (LENGTH-1)*2
    hop_size = int(fft_size/4)

    spec_librosa = librosa.core.stft(np.array(sig), n_fft=(LENGTH-1)*2, hop_length=hop_size, win_length=fft_size)
    return spec_librosa

def get_iSTFT_librosa(spec):
    fft_size = (LENGTH-1)*2
    hop_size = int(fft_size/4)
    inverse = librosa.core.istft(spec, hop_length=hop_size, win_length=fft_size)
    return inverse

def get_STFT_tf(sig):
    STFT = tf.signal.stft(np.array(sig), frame_length=(LENGTH-1)*2, frame_step=int((LENGTH-1)*2/4), fft_length=(LENGTH-1)*2)#,
    STFT = STFT.numpy()
    spec_tf = STFT.T
    return spec_tf

def get_iSTFT_tf(spec):
    STFT = tf.convert_to_tensor(spec.T)
    sig = tf.signal.inverse_stft(STFT, frame_length=(LENGTH-1)*2, frame_step=int((LENGTH-1)*2/4), fft_length=(LENGTH-1)*2)#,
    return sig.numpy()

def librosa_tf_comparison():
    time = np.arange(0, 1000, 0.1);
    sig = np.sin(time)

    #STFT level 1
    tf_STFT = get_STFT_tf(sig)
    lib_STFT = get_STFT_librosa(sig)

    tf_iSTFT = get_iSTFT_tf(tf_STFT)
    lib_iSTFT = get_iSTFT_librosa(lib_STFT)

    #STFT level 2
    tf_STFT2 = get_STFT_tf(tf_iSTFT)
    lib_STFT2 = get_STFT_librosa(lib_iSTFT)

    tf_iSTFT2 = get_iSTFT_tf(tf_STFT2)
    lib_iSTFT2 = get_iSTFT_librosa(lib_STFT2)


    #STFT level 3
    tf_STFT3 = get_STFT_tf(tf_iSTFT2)
    lib_STFT3 = get_STFT_librosa(lib_iSTFT2)

    tf_iSTFT3 = get_iSTFT_tf(tf_STFT3)
    lib_iSTFT3 = get_iSTFT_librosa(lib_STFT3)

    plt.plot(sig[:800])
    plt.plot(tf_iSTFT[:800])
    plt.plot(tf_iSTFT2[:800])
    plt.plot(tf_iSTFT3[:800])
    plt.show()

    plt.plot(sig[:800])
    plt.plot(lib_iSTFT[:800])
    plt.plot(lib_iSTFT2[:800])
    plt.plot(lib_iSTFT3[:800])
    plt.show()

librosa_tf_comparison()
```

Comment: Can you add some plots with a dummy data so it's reproducible?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi Done, thank you for the suggestion!